# In Cricket games, how is the ball synced with batsman's shot animation? How does the ball hit right at the center of the bat? How does this work?

Tags: unity, physics, animation, unreal-4, animation-states

I've been trying to figure this out for quite some time now.

In Cricket games, when the bowler bowls, and batsman takes a shot, how does the ball sync with batsman's shot animation?
For example, let's say the batsman hits a straight drive, how does the ball hit the bat perfectly?

Can anyone help me out with this?

I'm also curious  about how in football games, the player animations sync with the football. How does the player's foot correctly hit the ball?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've tagged this with both Unity and Unreal. Which engine are you using for this project at present?

Comment: I'm experimenting with both right now...

Comment: If you select one engine, answers can detail the specific implementation steps for that context. If you leave it open-ended, you'll tend to attract only answers that are more vague, outlining the overall strategy rather than specific steps.

Comment: I didn't understand the question. Why would you want to sync it since it would be projectile and its the player's skill that when he should hit the ball at what time or speed.

Answer (score 1):

Found some useful info in this thread (works with Unity) -
[Manipulating an animation towards a target object (ie. The hand and arm lean towards the target)](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/152320/manipulating-an-animation-towards-a-target-object-ie-the-hand-and-arm-lean-tow)

One useful approach would be to use IK to target the bat to position of the ball and blend it with the shot animation.

Comment: Thats right, you should use IK for this :)